# asp.net mvc ajax EnableClientValidation and parse returned data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, json, validation

i use ajax.beginform with EnableClientValidation. problem -the form sends data to controller in any case even the form is not correct -what the proiblem?

the second qusion- i return ajax data like this

```
return Json(new { value = "msg" });
```

how can i parse this data from javascript on view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Here's an extensive [step by step tutorial](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx) explaining how to implement validation with ASP.NET MVC 2 and how to enable client validation. If you follow it correctly you should not have any problems.
2. You could use the `OnSuccess` option:

   ```
   <% using (Ajax.BeginForm("SomeAction", new AjaxOptions {
       OnSuccess = "success"
   })) { %>
   ```

   where the `success` callback could look like this:

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   function success(data) {
       alert(data.get_object());
   }
   </script>
   ```

---

UPDATE:

Here's a working example:

- Model:

  ```
  public class Product
  {
      [Required]
      public string Name { get; set; }
  }
  ```
- Controller:

  ```
  public class HomeController : Controller
  {
      public ActionResult Index()
      {
          return View(new Product());
      }
      [HttpPost]
      public ActionResult Index(Product product)
      {
          return Json(new { status = "success" });
      }
  }
  ```
- View:

  ```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Url.Content("~/scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js") %>"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Url.Content("~/scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js") %>"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Url.Content("~/scripts/MicrosoftMvcValidation.js") %>"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function success(data) {
      alert(data.get_object().status);
  }
  </script>

  <% Html.EnableClientValidation(); %>
  <% using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "success" })) { %>
      <%= Html.LabelFor(x => x.Name) %>
      <%= Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name) %>
      <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Name) %>
      <input type="submit" value="Create" />
  <% } %>
  ```

Comment: i read this article, i do it like hi describe, but it work only for html.beginborm, but when i use ajax.beginform- post data go to controller even if clienc validation shows errors

Comment: Please see my update illustrating a working example of client validation with `Ajax.BeginForm`.

Comment: nope, here desision, may be you interested. article http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/19/aspnetmvc2-custom-validation.aspx but solution in comments second comment from end